# File access different with permalinks on and off

Tags: permalinks

I have a page with a link to a file in a password protected folder.

When I have permalinks turned off, clicking on the link starts the file download.

When I have permalinks turned on, clicking on the link takes me to Page Not Found, however, if I then go to the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the file starts downloading.

How can I make it so when permalinks are turned on, the file starts downloading on link click?

Comment: Thanks :) Any ideas about my Q?